# How long does Ubuntu take to install?

Tags: system-installation

I have been installing for about 45 mins and the install bar is still white.

Comment: It shouldn't take quite that long without showing any progress.  What was the last step you were on?

Comment: @user284382 : It depends on your hardware configuration. Specify your method of installing and where you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it takes me about 2 hours, all told.  But I tend to walk away from the computer once in a while, so it could probably be done a bit faster

Comment: thank you. I also had a hard time initially getting it to install. I booted from a usb as I just built this computer yesterday and had no other os on it. When it asked me about partitioning nothing came up so I just clicked on continue anyway.

Comment: What's your hardware?

Comment: It normally takes me 10 or 20 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it shouldn't take more than about 15 to 30 minutes, but you may have issues if you don't have a computer with a good amount of RAM. You said in another answer's comment that you had built the computer, so check out how large the RAM chips/sticks you used are. (Older chips are usually 256MB or 512MB.)